# How to retrieve every nth row in Azure Storage?

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, data-visualization, powerbi, azure-table-storage

I have the following scenario. Information collected every minute is sent to and stored in Azure table storage. Now, I am trying to display this data in a graph. If I only show data for the last day, it would be relatively easy to filter through 1440 (24 * 60) data points to only display 200. However, if we consider showing data over a month, I would have to handle over 40,000 data points (24 * 60 * 30). However I only would need to show 200 of those data points. Assuming 40,000 points, I would only select every 200th data point, or row. Is this functionality possible in azure storage. Or would I have to select bunches at a time, select the 200th element and then move on to the next data set?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the 200th data point in your case. You could either use `$top` entities from a set, or the `$filter`query to get the results you want. I'd rather suggest using **PowerBI** which is free and compatible with Table storage, it basically turns data into graphs, and you can apply additional filters to what suits you. 
You can read more about it here:

Powerbi links:https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/integrations/azure-table-storage/ 
And https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/